# My spring-boot application can't find my hibernate.properties on the classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to run my spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE application from the Linux command line like so:

```
java -verbose \
     -classpath '/home/hadoop/config/engine/' \
     -jar ~/jars/dbp.engine-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-spring-boot.jar \
     --spring.config.additional-location=/home/hadoop/config/engine/merged.properties ...
```

The application fails with the following message:

> Application run failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
> Failed to parse configuration class
> [gov.afms.dbp.engine.BiobankEngineApplication];    nested exception is
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> **class path resource** **[hibernate.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist**
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]

Why can't the application find `hibernate.properties` when it is on the classpath?

```
ls -l /home/hadoop/config/engine/hibernate.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 552 May 25  2022 /home/hadoop/config/engine/hibernate.properties
```

Comment: You can't mix `-classpath` and `-jar` It's one or the other. Config should be in your resources folder and accessed via `"/hibernate.properties"`. Although if you're mixing two it could be different. In which case, ditch `-jar` *But* then you're going to have to name your main class

Comment: Thanks, @g00se!  I understand what you say about mixing -classpath and -jar.  I'd like to be able to specify where the hibernate.properties is via a command line argument.  I've tried over a dozen different command lines, but haven't hit the magic combination yet.

Comment: Let me ask you first: why is it that you don't want that hibernate properties file *in* the jar?

Comment: @g00se - the hibernate.properties includes sensitive information (e.g., login/password),  We have a tool that scans our jar for potential security problems, and that would cause a problem that would prevent us deploying our jar to the target environment.

Comment: Hehe. I don't see how that could be safer *outside* the jar but in any case, something like `java -verbose -classpath /home/hadoop/config/engine:~/jars/dbp.engine-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-spring-boot.jar --spring.config.additional-location=/home/hadoop/config/engine/merged.properties a.b.c.Application` (where the last argument is the f.q. name of your main class)